# t4 template in database project - generated files are not children of the .tt file

Tags: entity-framework, t4

For reference, I am following [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520.aspx), about 2/3 of the way down the page where `EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager` is mentioned for the first time.

I am attempting to write some t4 templates to generate insert, update, and delete stored procedures for every table in a database project.  Generating the actual code is no problem, the issue I am having is the generated .sql files are being added at the same level as the .tt file in the project, and not as children.  This is annoying because I have a lot of non-generated SPs as well, and I don't want the generated and non-generated mixed together.

The website mentioned above has the following image demonstrating the expected output (which is what I want):

[image: good]

But this is what I am getting -- the generated `EF_Insert_*.sql` files (except for the blank `EF CRUD Procedures.sql`) are not being added to the project with `<DependentUpon>` and are showing up in the root of the `Stored Procedures` directory:

[image: bad]

I realize this is a bit of a cosmetic thing, but is there any way to fix this?  Here is the template, stripped down to just write the table name in the file.  GetAllTables() just returns a list of tables.

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".sql" #>
<#@ SqlModelDirective processor="SqlModelDirectiveProcessor" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Model" #>
<#@ include file="EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#> 
<#
    List<TSqlObject> allTables = GetAllTables();

    var fileManager = EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.Create(this);  

    foreach (var table in allTables)
    {
        fileManager.StartNewFile(string.Format("EF_Insert_{0}.sql", table.Name.Parts[1]));
        WriteLine("--{0}", table.Name.Parts[1]);
    }

    fileManager.Process();        
#>
```

Comment: Same problem here... I've also tried non EF specific [.ttinclude](http://damieng.com/blog/2009/11/06/multiple-outputs-from-t4-made-easy-revisited) which works good in c# projects and the result was same. Seams like a bug in VS.